# CSS image moving on resize

Tags: html, css, image, resize

Image is moving in position after browser window is resized. Not sure why. Can anyone explain why?

```
#me img {
height: 200px;
width: 200px;
border-radius: 50%;
left: 850px;
position: absolute;
}
```

Comment: It seems that shifting it over with a % value does the trick. Can anyone explain why this is the case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because the `img` is absolutely positioned `850px` to the left. Thus, when resizing the window, it will always be in the same position, as it is a set `px` value. Setting a `%` based value shifts the `img` as it is a percentage based upon the parent - in this case being the body, which is the window that is being resized.

See what happens when you remove the positioning: http://jsfiddle.net/JoshC/6jH9x/

If it must be absolutely positioned, you should consider adding `position:relative` to the parent, making the child absolutely positioned relative to the parent.